# FCM Notification is not working if app is closed like GCM

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am replacing my GCM code with FCM for Notification but I am not able to get notification when app is fully closed. In GCM `WAKE_LOCK` permission is used to app stay on. Anyone have idea how to stay on App in FCM.

Comment: FCM works even after app closed,i faced same issue with me and this issue was from server side,they were sending me header value in push notification,after comment this header code it worked..

Comment: Can you tell what type of header you got in response? @pkgrover